# Typescript: variable value undefined despite being initialized in constructor

Tags: typescript, console, namespaces, undefined

I have `num1: number`, then

```
constructor(){
  ...
  this.num1 = 0;
}
```

inside a class.

But when log inside a function `console.log(this.num1)` or `console.log(typeof this.num1)`, I get **undefined** both times.

Why is the value of my variable undefined here?

Comment: Hi!  Please review the guidelines about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what constitutes a [mcve].  I'm guessing the function in which you are having trouble has a different value of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) than you are expecting, but without more info it's hard to be any more specific.  Good luck!

Comment: How is the method being called? As @jcalz mentioned, most likely the value of `this` is not the instance of the class.

Comment: You click a button and then this event is handled by calling the aforenamed function which needs num1 of the current class instance

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by others the likely culprit is that `this` is not what you expect in function.

If you have a class like this:

```js
class Foo {
    public myValue: number;
    constructor() { this.myValue = 0; }
    barOne() { console.log(this.myValue); }
    barTwo = () => { console.log(this.myValue); }
}
```

the `barOne` and `barTwo` will behave differently when used ass callbacks by an entity external to the class.

This is the case when using a class instance method as a callback to a button, like in your case.

It is useful to dive deeper in to how `this` works in javascript and typescript (javascript behaves the same as typescript if ecmascript 6 is available) and there are lots of good articles about it out there.

But the simple solution is to use "arrow functions", the way I did with the `barTwo` method above.